# How to setup Teamviewer on remote server (SSH only)?

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, remote-desktop, teamviewer

I have a VPS with Debian 9 and want to run Teamviewer with XFCE. Having only SSH access makes this difficult. (I have read Teamviewer's guides but they didn't help) Here is what I have tried so far:

1. After creating a fresh instance I have simply installed XFCE4 like so:

   `sudo apt-get install xfce4`
2. Installed teamviewer from [www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux/](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux/)

   `sudo dpkg -i teamviewer-<version>.deb # complaint about dependencies
    sudo apt-get install -f
    sudo dpkg -i teamviewer-<version>.deb # works now`
3. Reboot
4. Run teamviewer (`teamviewerd` and `lightdm` auto started)

   `sudo teamviewer passwd <password>
    sudo teamviewer info # shows me the teamviewer-id for connection`
5. Connect with teamviewer-id on other computer and enter teamviewer password
6. Enter user and password in Linux XFCE login screen (lightdm)
7. Teamviewer hangs and only shows Debian desktop background

My guess is Teamviewer has a problem with the fact that the VPS doesn't have a display.